# How can I get all users who have installed my facebook app without being friend?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

That's the question. I have developed a Facebook App that implements the login button to Login in facebook. I am able to get all friends who has installed my app, but to do that I have to be a friend.

I wonder if there isn't a "fan page" to be fan of.. or something like that, because it's very unpractical to force Users to be friend of mine.

Comment: There is no list of all app users. If you need one, you have to build it yourself – by storing their user ids somewhere server-side when they log in.

Comment: thanks! It seems it's the only way